# Node.js azure web app can't access my routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have the following `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());
const uploadRoute = require('./routes/upload');

app.use(cors());

app.use(uploadRoute(router));
app.use(router);
http.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:80');
});
```

And the following web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now i add this to my server which makes it look like this:

[image]

I then attempt to start the server using forever `forever start index.js`
then i go to my website and try out a route but it just gives me an error code 500.

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, you could modify your `index.js` like below and try again:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());
const uploadRoute = require('./routes/upload');

app.use(cors());

app.use(uploadRoute(router));
app.use(router);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
          console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
          });
```

Also, for 500 error, you'll need to enable logging of `stdout` and `stderr` for troubleshooting and see what the logs say. To enable debugging, please follow the steps:

1. Create file `iisnode.yml` in your root folder (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) if not exists.
2. Add the following lines to it.

   loggingEnabled: true
   logDirectory: iisnode

After that done, you can find logs in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode`.

For more info, please refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug#enable-logging).